# Get Format used when formatting a date as 'shortDate'

Tags: angular, localization, date-formatting

How can we get the format used, when a date is formatted as a `shortDate` (or any other formatting). Background: Depending on the local, a the 'shortDate' formats dates differently.
Example:

- "de" formatted date 13.10.21 (DD.MM.YYYY)
- "en-US" formatted date 10/13/21 (MM/DD/YYYY)
- "en-GB" formatted date 13/10/2021 (DD/MM/YYYY)

Since our user can switch languages, it is not obvious which format is used. Which then can be quite confusing. To help him we want to display the used date-format, but I cannot find a way to get it.

Stackblitz sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kyjabd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

What we have tried:
We looked, how the `formatDate` gets the format information, however the `getNamedFormat` function is not exported.

Samplecode

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  deDate;
  enDate;
  enGbDate;

  constructor() {
    const date = Date.now();
    this.deDate = formatDate(date, 'shortDate', 'de');
    this.enDate = formatDate(date, 'shortDate', 'en');
    this.enGbDate = formatDate(date, 'shortDate', 'en-GB');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getLocaleDateFormat` from angular/common package:

```
import {  FormatWidth, getLocaleDateFormat } from '@angular/common';
```

then

```
getLocaleDateFormat(locale, FormatWidth.Short)
```

Where locale is string value such as en-US etc.

LocaleDateFormat returned is correct and based on this Angular is formatting the date. If you are looking for exact format, you might need to create a map of short date format as per locale and get it from there:

```
getLocaleDateString(locale): string {
    // All you locale short format goes here
    const formats = {
      "de": "DD.MM.YYYY",
      "en-GB": "DD/MM/YYYY",
    };
  
    return formats[locale] || "dd/MM/yyyy";
 }
```

Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cuu2jo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Seems to be what I'm looking for (example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4f5ciy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts ). But I don't get why the formats are so different (dd.MM.yy, M/d/yy, dd/MM/y). Can I somehow get that in a "nice" way, so it is "DD/MM/YYYY" all the time?